# Setting Custom axis values pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, python-2.7

I have a plot in a tkinter.Toplevel window and I would like to have it use a custom spaced x-axis.  Currently it is set as default so the numbers are evenly spaced (0,5,10,15... etc.).  I would like to have a tick mark for each data point I have (example 2,6,15,30).  I am sure it is just some key word under some header, but I cannot figure out which one it is.  Below is an example of the code that it would be going into.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Toplevel(width=2000)
f = Figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)
zeroy = [0,25]
zerox = [0, 35]
p3 = ax.plot(zerox, zeroy, 'k-')
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, root)
toolbar.grid(row=1, sticky=tk.W) 
toolbar.update() 
button = tk.Button(root, text='Quit', command = root.destroy)
button.grid(row=2)
root.mainloop()
```

I have tried to use `ax.xticks(...)` and `f.add_axes(xticks=[1,2,5,7]` but these didn't work.  I have also tried a variety of other weak attempts without success.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ax.set_xticks(ticks=[0,2,4,5,30,50])
```

Discovered this after messing with my code some more.